# How do I make scaled images look better in Java/OpenGL?

Tags: java, image, opengl

Here are two pictures of the same image:

this is what it looks like when viewed in preview...

[image]

and this is how it looks in my game...

[image]

Obviously the character is scaled down in my game, however, when I scale down the sprite in preview or pixelmator, it is still smooth.  Even when the image is at a 1:1 scale it still has the jagged edges.

This is my render method

```
public void render(Camera camera, List<Entity> entities) {
    shader.loadViewMatrix(Main.createViewMatrix(camera));

    //per textured model
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(((RenderComponent) entities.get(0).getComponent(EntityComponentType.RENDER)).texturedModel.getRawModel().getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    for(Entity e : entities) {
        RenderComponent render = (RenderComponent) e.getComponent(EntityComponentType.RENDER);

        //load transformation matrix per entity
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(Main.createTransformationMatrix(render.position, render.rx, render.ry, render.getScaleX(), render.getScaleY()));
        shader.loadSprite((AnimationComponentContainer) e.getComponent(EntityComponentType.ANIMATION));

        //activate texture for each entity
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, render.getTexturedModel().getTexture().getTextureID());

        //render entity
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, render.getTexturedModel().getRawModel().getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }

    //per textured model
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And in my fragment shader I sample the image

```
vec4 color = texture(sampler, pass_TextureCoords);
```

and remove transparency

```
if(color.a < 0.5) discard;
out_Color = vec4(totalDiffuse, 1) * color;
```

My question is, how do I prevent the jagged edges from occurring (they are most prominent around his pants)? Or how do I smooth them out?  The image itself if 512x1024

Comment: Post some code that you are using to display your graphics

Comment: @Confiqure does that help?

Comment: What in particular do you see as the problem? Because "look better" doesn't seem very specific.

Comment: @NicolBolas You can see it throughout the entire character sprite, but it is most prominent on his pants.  I am talking about the jagged edges.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3053027: The reason I ask that is because I see many things which could be considered "wrong". The fact that the in-engine colors don't match the original image's colors. And so forth. So you should edit your question so that we know it's specifically about the edges and not about the other issues.

Comment: @NicolBolas I hope you understand my question now, thanks for helping me be more clear.  I hope you can help me find a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the internal rendering resolution of the game is large enough for the full image, and be sure that the game isn't casting any light onto the sprite itself, because it looks like the character is interacting with that green light over there and it's causing some gradient issues on the pants.

Comment: It is not the light, I removed all lighting and it still had the same problem.  What is the internal rendering resolution? If you mean the window size, then it should be good, it is 1280 x 720.  Is there anything else it could be?